# How to filter a query for arbitrary results?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am writing a program for data analysis. To group my results I wrote those functions:

```
def prepare_data(sample_list, group_option):
    if group_option == None:
        group_parameter = None
    elif group_option == 'sample':
        group_parameter = sample_parameters.sample
    elif group_option == 'parameter':
        group_parameter = (sample_parameters.speed, sample_parameters.gap, sample_parameters.temperature, sample_parameters.volume)
```

This function determines how to group my different samples for later calculation. This should be the only place to make entries regarding grouping.

```
def group_data(sample_list, group_parameter):
    query = session.query(sample_measurements_raw.data, group_parameter).filter(sample_parameters.idsample_parameters == sample_measurements_raw.sample_id).filter(sample_parameters.useless == 0).filter(sample_parameters.sample.in_(sample_list)).group_by(group_parameter)

    data_table = pandas.DataFrame()

    for row in query:
        data_table = pandas.concat([data_table, (calculate_data(sample_list, row.keys))[-1:-2]], axis = 'columns', join = 'outer')

    return data_table
```

This function get a list of samples and the group parameter (consisting of orm.attributes). It the searches in that list for samples with the same parameters and groups them. It then iterates through all unique parameter sets which are passed to another function:

```
def calculate_data(sample_list, parameter):
    query = session.query(sample_measurements_raw.data).filter(sample_parameters.idsample_parameters == sample_measurements_raw.sample_id).filter(sample_parameters.useless == 0).filter(sample_parameters.sample.in_(sample_list)).filter(parameter)

    data_table = pandas.DataFrame()

    for row in query:
        data_table = pandas.concat([data_table, pandas.read_json(row.data, orient = 'split').set_index('nm').rename(columns = {" %T": parameter})], axis = 'columns', join = 'outer')

    data_table[parameter + '_mean'] = data_table.mean(axis = 1)
    data_table[parameter + '_std'] = data_table[data_table.columns[0:-1]].std(axis = 1)

    return data_table
```

Here the problem starts. That function should get the parameters of the unique groups and perform a filter to get all of the data matching the exact parameters of that group. Please keep in mind that the number of supplied parameters can change.

The question:

How to filter for those parameters I got from `group_data`?

I hope my question is understandable and thanks for the help!

**EDIT:**

A concrete example would be:

The list to start with looks something like that:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hetux.png)

The table is still expanding, so I want to edit the `group_parameter` in the first function. Everything else should be derived from that.

1. Group data by `group_parameter` and create list. That list consists of `row` objects with member statements (eg. `row.speed`, `row.gap`). Number and name of the statements is dependent on `group_parameters`.
2. Iterate through list and fetch all data where the values match exactly with the values of the list entry. Therefor the expression should look something like that: `.filter(sample_parameters.speed == row.speed, sample_parameters.gap == row.gap)`

Question:

How to get a arbitray set of parameters (eg. `sample_parameters.speed`, `sample_parameters.gap`,...) from that list and filter by them in the next query?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem correctly, your provided functions are not the problem but the input format for the second functions needs to be pre-processed. So, to generalize your question: how to dynamically query for changing unique values from a returned data table?

I can -quickly- think of using df.Series.unique() to solve your problem.

```
#iterates through a list of unique df.Seriesvalues
for row in group_data.Parameters.unique: 
    # do something
```

However, there should be optimization potential performance-wise. For more information about, i.e., arguments for df.Series.unique(),
see [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html)

Comment: Not quite. 
Maybe a more concrete example will clear it up. Please see original post.